# Is My Question Relevant on G.SE?: My 3D Games crashing in these scenarios

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/my-3d-games-crashing-in-these-scenarios) on the main site. I want to move it to SuperUser as suggested by @James in the comments. Can a moderator move it to SuperUser, but will a acceptable answer there be applicable to our site as well?

I am hesitant to even ask a question there. I have browsed their database for my problem and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/54807/how-to-diagnose-why-pc-is-freezing-in-3d-application), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/76901/why-is-my-pc-freezing-in-3d-games), and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/378292/computer-keep-crashing-when-starting-3d-applications-games).

But they do not answer my specific question/scenario? Will it get closed?

Please let me know, in which case I will delete my question on our main site and post there.

What do I tag this under? Discussion?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 4):

Videogame troubleshooting questions are on-topic for Gaming and thus there is no need for us to close the question here as off-topic. Without closing the question here as off-topic, I can't migrate.

Comment: Just to add and suggest, since it's on topic, you could try cross posting to super user (as a new question) -- worst case scenario, it'll be closed in super user

Comment: @JuanManuel That doesn't seem like the best idea to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: I thought we generally sent hardware specific issues to SuperUser?

Comment: @James and generally Super User doesn't want to do any videogame troubleshooting.

Comment: This seemed to be a hardware issue though, and not game specific. Just utilizing the GPU seemed to lock things up?

Comment: Problems about hardware or drivers or what have you should totally be on Super User.  This isn't a video game specific issue as described, or at least there's a low enough probability to warrant posting over there.  IMO hardware issues never belong here either, but that's just me.  Thankfully, OP crossposted, and it's attracting decent discussion.  superuser.com/questions/404962/my-3d-games-crashing-in-these-scenarios